# In paragraph form field with label underneath

Tags: css, forms, webforms, label

I'd like to have an input box in the middle of a paragraph, with the label in smaller text underneath it. Kind of like:

```
Hello [________________], This is to inform you 
       (Customer Name)
that the [____________] you ordered is no longer
          (Item Name)
available.
```

I thought it would be pretty easy to do, but my brain doesn't appear to be working today. Is it possible to do this with just CSS, and in a simple enough manner that it can be adapted to different forms easily?

Comment: Would it be possible to put the `Label` and `Input` in a `Div` together? I've tried a couple of ways, but I either they float weird or the rest of the sentence after the div starts on a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what i did, it is not perfect but show you a way to go.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.input {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1.8em;
}
.input label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 60%;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
input {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    Hello
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="customer" id="customer" />
        <label for="customer">(Customer name)</label>
    </div>,
    this is to inform you that the
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="item" id="item" />
        <label for="item">(Item name)</label>
    </div>,
    you order is no longer available.
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, that IS perfect. Well, obviously color/style needs to change, but that is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: @aslum: You're welcome. This is why SO exists ;-). The color was useful to me (and maybe to you) to see the exact area of each box. Note that you can safely remove the margin-(right|left) properties. Re-read the code, I'll clean it up.

Comment: inline-block, so that is what it's for. I love it. Also a nice use of absolute positioning on the label to collapse the height of the div to the input.

Comment: Yeah, I often put primary color to get stuff to the right position. Thanks again!

Comment: So a little multi-browser checking later, and it works in everything but IE... in IE the inputs are left justified and labels are right justified, and in both cases take up a whole line... eg output is (substituting » for newlines since I can't do them in a comment:

    Hello »
    [_______]                                  (Customer Name) »
    this is to inform you that the »
    [_______]                                      (Item Name) »

Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: @aslum: I know what cause that, the poor support of IE for CSS. Check with google for a workaround. An hint: search for "internet explorer inline-block".

Comment: @mg: Thanks, that looks like it's the info I needed... I'll check it out on Wednesday.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing spectacularly simple comes to my mind.

My alternative would be to set the default input values to "Customer Name" and "Item Name" respectively. With a dash of JavaScript, you can automatically clear the input when the user gives it focus. An extra sprinkle will refill the input with "Customer Name" and "Item Name" if the input is left empty when the user blurs it.

Warning: I have little idea about JavaScript and its cross-browser compatibility issues. For example, I think `getElementsByClassName` is not implemented in some versions of IE. Take this code as an example of what I mean rather than production code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Inline form</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var valueHints = []
    window.onload = function() {
      var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("value-hint");
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        valueHints[inputs[i].id] = inputs[i].value;
        inputs[i].onfocus = function() {
          if (valueHints[this.id] == this.value) {
            this.value = "";
          }
        }
        inputs[i].onblur = function() {
          if (this.value == "") {
            this.value = valueHints[this.id];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .value-hint {
      color:#999999;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello <input class="value-hint" id="customer" type="text" value="Customer Name"></span>, This is to inform you that the <input class="value-hint" id="item" type="text" value="Item Name"> you ordered is no longer available.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'd really like to try and avoid javascript.